# PHP/MYSQL - Multiple connections to the same database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two files:

**config.php**:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("$dbhost","$dbuser","$dbpass","$dbname");
```

**ads.php** (config.php require_once):

```
$query1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * From XXXX where id = 'XXXX'");

$query2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM XXXX2 WHERE id = 'XXXX2'");
```

I have more than 40 different queries `mysqli_query()` using `$con`. Please keep in mind that all my logic is procedural style, not object oriented.

My two questions are:

1. am I connecting to the DB using a different connection on every query? Or just once when the first one is executed? Is there a better way to do this?
2. I understand that it is not mandatory to close a mysql connection since it closes itself, however since we have millions of consults sometimes a few can hang and stay for more than 10 seconds after the user left the PHP file. If I wanted to close a connection, should I put mysqli_close($con) at the end of the file (after the 40 consults) or at the end of each consult (40 times)?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If yours is working code, you should better ask your question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: A mysql connection is even used persistently over multiple http requests. Everything else would indeed be a huge performance issue. That means that closing the connection would actually slow things down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reusing the connection initiated in `mysqli_connect`.

A better way could be to use or create a DataHandler and implement PDOs. It could allow you to perform timing analytics on queries, automate binding parameters, destroy the connection once its finished with etc.

Call `mysqli_close($con)` at the end of the file. Also null `$con` to mark for garbage collection.

Once finished with the information from each step you could also call;
`mysqli_free_result($query1)` to [free memory](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php) associated to the statement handle